# How can I find actual logic php file in form's action path?

Tags: forms

```
<form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout woocommerce-checkout" action="http://localhost:10010/shop-2/checkout/"
```

I am using woocommerce plugin. this is checkout page form's html element. I just wondering how can i find action's php file location. e.g) normally I saw code like that

where is the php file?

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer you need. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, check out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work. As a rule, many in the community consider questions about third-party plugins (such as woocommerce) off-topic. Have you tried asking the plugin author? You can find out what questions are a good fit [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).